# Simple AWS IOT Web Application Dashboard to Publish and Subscribe

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, web-applications, aws-sdk-js

I am developing a Dashboard to publish information to a topic and display received (subscribed) information from AWS cloud.

I am testing using `IoT Core->Test->enter the topic to publish and subscribe`.

I am using AWS Javascript SDK, I can Publish/Subscribe using the `jobs-example.js` (i.e) `node examples/jobs-example.js -f certs -H xxx.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`.

I used `"jobs.publish('testTopic',  "Test Success");" to publish and "jobs.subscribe('testTopic');"` to subscribe.

Now I need know how to integrate it in my browser Web application where the user enters a topic and types a message in a textbox which will be published to AWS cloud and display the received (subscribed) message in another text box.

Comment: Somehow I managed to Publish a data to cloud by including "https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.608.0.min.js" in the html file and used `AWS.config.update({
       accessKeyId:  "xxxx",
       secretAccessKey: "yyy",
         region: 'us-west-2'
});` and used `let iotPromise = await iotData.publish(params).promise();` to publish data. Is there any api/way to subscribe and receive in the Javascript file?

Comment: can you please share your sample code you've used to publish data to AWS IoT Core. I have already registered a thing and have an custom endpoint. Thanks